# How do I correctly align, center, and number a multi-step arithmetic problem?

Tags: align, columns, arithmetic

As indicated in the picture, I would like to have several things:

1. Numbered steps (if possible, on the left side)
2. Aligned and centered properly, so it looks professional.
3. The summation in step #2 needs to be aligned properly with plus symbol.

[image: How it should look]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{l@{}l@{}l}
        5 & 4 & \rightarrow 50 + 4 \\
        \times  & 7 \\
    \cline{1-2}
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \begin{array}{l@{}l@{}l}
        50 & \times 7 & = 350 \\
        4 & \times 7 & = +28 \\
        \cline{3-3}
        & & 378
    \end{array}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Welcome to TeX.SE
- I guess that you looking for the following

[image]

```
\documentclass[leqno]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
With \verb+enumerate+:
\begin{enumerate}
\item\hfil   $\begin{array}[t]{rl}
        54        & \rightarrow 50 + 4    \\
        \times 7  &                       \\
    \cline{1-1}
    \end{array}$
\item\hfil   $\begin{array}[t]{r @{} r}
    50 \times 7 = &         350     \\
    4  \times 7 = & +\phantom{3}28  \\
        \cline{2-2}
                  & 378
    \end{array}$
\end{enumerate}

Or with \verb+align+:
\begin{align}
&   \begin{array}[t]{rl}
        54         & \rightarrow 50 + 4    \\
        \times  7  &                       \\
    \cline{1-1}
    \end{array}     \\[2ex]
&   \begin{array}[t]{r @{} r}
    50 \times 7 = &         350     \\
    4  \times 7 = & {}+\phantom{3}28  \\
        \cline{2-2}
                   & 378
    \end{array}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there anywhere else to lookup these commands, packages, etc. besides https://texdoc.org/index.html?

Comment: Can you discuss your thought process on deciding which packages to use and the arguments needed to format it properly?

Comment: @anon, almost each package has own documentation, which are part of your LaTeX. Installation. Overviews and introductory text you can find on wiki/LaTeX/... Also is worth to see https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf.